# Select single row from database table with one field different and all other being same

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database table with 8 fields say Table(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h).For some rows one of the field is different(say 4 different a values) while all other field values(b-h) in the schema are same.I have to make a table selecting just one rows from such rows with different a's but same b-h.That is I can select any one of the different a's and keep b-h same which they are and display it in table as 1 single row instead of 4.

Comment: Are you saying that `b = c = d..` for every row?  Or are you saying that all column b's are the same, all column c's are the same, etc..?

Comment: @RBarryYoung No b1 = b2, c1=c2,d1=d2,e1=e2... where 1 and 2 are two different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(a) a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
FROM mytable
GROUP BY b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

Comment: If you only have "Min(a)", then the output column will not have a name

Comment: Sorrygot it u are referencing Min a as a.Thanks